# Looking for why my code is not registering the binding for xamarin forms for pulling an image from one page and placing it on the button

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So basically i placed a binding in the source for an image button in xamarin and i am trying to pull an image from another page in the app and replace the current source for the image button.

I have tried the following code for setting up the binding in xamarin:

```
<xct:AvatarView BackgroundColor="Transparent" Scale=".3" Source="{Binding Image1}" TranslationX="150" TranslationY="-150" x:Name="Emote1"/>
```

This will call the binding and designate what will be there:

```
public string Image1 { get; set; }
```

And the image should be taking the image from the page on the app and adding it to another page:

I have tried switching around some of the variables but i have not found a good solution any help would be great I am using Visual Studios btw

Comment: How is this related to C?

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  Your question is pretty hard to follow - instead of describing your code it is usually much more effective to show us the actual code.  And when you do post code, please format it so its readable.

Comment: Get there in steps. Make sure each step works, before doing the next step. First step is to show an image, given a string name. Second step is to make that a binding - WITHOUT involving some other page. It will be the name of a FILE (or a RESOURCE). Third step is to carefully describe what you are trying to do, that involves two pages. What is the role of the first page? Why getting image (or image name) from there? DON'T try to bind to an image on another page; that isn't how Xamarin works. Images should be in files. Then you show them on each page, via the file name.

Comment: If you change the Image1 property, you have to raise PropertyChanged event